# How to write a regular expression in no particular order?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to do a javascript check on a string.
The string must have 6 letters and 2 numbers but not necessarily in that order, also 2 numbers and 6 letters.

At the time i have:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{6,}[0-9]{2,}$/;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can it be mixed? Do the numbers have to be together?

Comment: Why didn't you accept any answer ? Do you have a problem with Federico's one ?

Answer (score 6):

```
^(?=(.*[0-9]){2})(?=(.*[A-Za-z]){6})[A-Za-z0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider adding explanations to your answer.

Comment: Note that this (good) one, contrary to what seemed to be OP's question, doesn't accept more than 8 characters but it may be fixed by just changing the last quantifier.

Comment: you can also use `a-z` with `/i` modifier instead of `[A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `|` pipe to give your regex two alternatives:

```
/^[a-z]{6}\d\d$|^\d\d[a-z]{6}$/i
```

Comment: This only covers a very small set of possibilities, or I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @dystroy - I asked the OP for clarification above. Will update if needed. From the question it seems that this is what they want: "The string must have **6 letters and 2 numbers** but not necessarily in that order, also **2 numbers and 6 letters**".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is how to check for a mixed set of letters and digits with at least 2 digits and 6 letters, I personally would do it like this :

```
var str = "abc12def";
var digits = str.match(/\d/g).length;
var ok = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$/.test(str)
         && digits >=2 && str.length-digits>=6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer what I think, took some time for me to post.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{6}[\d]{2}|[\d]{2}[a-zA-Z]{6}$
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
/^([a-z]{6}|[0-9]{2})([a-z]{6}|[0-9]{2})$/i
```

You can try here: http://rubular.com/r/pmYxoX6qwD

Comment: That will also match `1234` and `abcdefghijkl`.